# Pentagon axis of symmetry

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, symmetry

Quick question: Can a pentagon have an axis of symmetry passing through two (one, none) of its vertices?

I'm given the following definition for axis of symmetry: A figure is said to have an axis of symmetry, $a$, if this figure is symmetric to itself about the line, $a$, i.e. if for any point of the figure the symmetric point also belongs to the figure.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you talking about a regular pentagon?

Comment: Why is "context missing" the reason for the vote to close?  The definition of axis of symmetry is given here, which is pretty good context.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose the line of symmetry passes through 1 (or 2, or 3) vertices. Where are all the vertices? Draw some pictures!

Answer (score 2):

Note that to be a line of symmetry, there should be an equal number of vertices on each side of the line. Consequently, there must be an even number of vertices not lying on the line, so the line must pass through an odd number of vertices. It is impossible to have a pentagon with all 5 vertices lying on the same line. A line passing through one vertex can certainly work (for regular pentagons, the "[home plate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_plate#Home_plate)" shape, etc.). Is it possible that a line passing through 3 vertices of a pentagon to be a line of symmetry?

Comment: The axis of symmetry in a regular pentagon is the segment drawn from a vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side. If this is true, I don't see how it would pass through more than one vertex at a time. Can the vertex also be the midpoint of a side?? I don't think so, so I'm going with it can only pass through one (I used the home plate shape).

Comment: new to this site, so forgive me if I'm not responding to 'Cameron Blue' correctly. I'm the one who asked the original question, just looking to see if my reasoning is correct ^^

Comment: The vertex can't be the midpoint of a side. It must be an endpoint. You're correct that a line of symmetry can't pass through more than one vertex at a time, but the home plate shape doesn't prove it. Label your vertices clockwise by $1,2,3,4,5,$ with $1$ the vertex that the line of symmetry *must* pass through. If vertex $2$ lies on the line of symmetry, what can you say about vertex $5$? Do we still have a pentagon, then? If vertex $3$ lies on the line of symmetry, what can you say about vertex $4$? Do we still have a pentagon, then? Likewise, $4,5$ can't lie on the line of symmetry.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i'll work with that & get back to you.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thanks again

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help.